# Read or open a file using "fuzzy match" filename - Python

Tags: python, regex, file, io

Given a list of files in a directory:

```
import os
os.listdir('system-outputs/newstest2016/ru-en')
```

[out]:

```
['newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast.4524.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-Phrase.4383.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.AMU-UEDIN.4458.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.NRC.4456.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.online-A.0.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.online-B.0.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.online-F.0.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.online-G.0.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.PROMT-Rule-based.4277.ru-en',
 'newstest2016.uedin-nmt.4309.ru-en']
```

And then I have the input:

```
filename, suffix = 'newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast', 'ru-en'
```

Using the filename, if I want to do a regex match such that I can read the file `newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast.4524.ru-en`, I could do:

```
import re
fin = open(next(_fn for _fn in os.list('system-outputs/newstest2016/ru-en') if re.match(filename + '.*.' + suffix, _fn) for _fn in))
```

**But is there a way to read/open a "fuzzy match" filename?** There must be a better way than the crude `re.match` way above.

It's okay to assume that there should always be one clear match from the `os.listdir`.

Comment: What would you define as a "clear match"? Fuzzy match by definition can match several items so implementing such a thing is highly unlikely unless the fuzziness is well defined.

Comment: There's this `4524 ` number in `newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast.4524.ru-en` that I don't know about beforehand, so the regex is basically trying to guess that.

Comment: If it is prefix based as you suggest take a look at the answer given. To me it looks like you want `'.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-2])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` as suggested, but it can give several matches. I'd go with the pattern that seems to be:

```
filenames = [
    'newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast.4524.ru-en',
    # ...
    'newstest2016.PROMT-Rule-based.4277.ru-en',
    'newstest2016.uedin-nmt.4309.ru-en'
]
my_filename, suffix = 'newstest2016.AFRL-MITLL-contrast', 'ru-en'
for filename in filenames:
    *fn, suff = filename.split('.')
    if ('.'.join(fn[:-1]), suff) == (my_filename, suffix):
        break
else:
    filename = None
# `filename` is now set to real file name
```

I use python3.x for nicer syntax but this is easy to port to python2.x.

Comment: As you're breaking the loop on correct match (using a 'strictly single match' info) I expect this should be faster for large filename lists. Can you please add some benchmarks? On a (far) side note, I am not the one who downvoted your answer!

Comment: Not sure benchmarks are needed here. If this is a process that should be fast some preprocessing and using mappings (and the fact that keys are a `set`) would do far better so I see no point in benchmarking :-)